.htaccess map to /books or /books/ or /books/<url_slug>
I am trying to map.htaccess to /books or /books/ or /books/<url_slug>:
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1 [R=301,L]

# Map /books/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^books$ book.php [NC,L,QSA]

Result:

book.php:
<?php

echo '<h1>Books</h1>';

?>


I think your first rule block is winning. The /? would be an optional trailing slash, so both /book and /book/ would match that, if I'm reading this correctly.

Honestly, I would encourage you to use a single router that maps everything that the server can't resolve to a single PHP script where you can perform logic that is platform-agnostic, easier to test and debug, and (IMHO) much easier to read and add comments to.

@ChrisHaas, yes, it means that either /books or /books/should work, with this:^([^/]+)/?$, but maybe: ^books?/$`

But the L directive means "last", so no additional rules should be processed.

I fail to understand the idea behind that first rule. To me it looks like an endless redirection loop ... Requests to /book are externally redirected to /book which will get matched again in the next request the browser sends as a rection to the redirection. So why the /?? Why the ?. To me it appears that this rule only makes sense without that trailing slash being treated as optional. And you then have to make sure that there is no other factor forcing a trailing slash again.

Apart from that you need to make sure those rules get applied at all. How did you do that?

Solved yesterday.
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^books/?$ book.php [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^books/([^/]*)?$ book.php?title=$1 [QSA,NC,L]


First, I'm glad you found a solution that worked for you. That said, code-only answers are frowned upon here, even if you are the OP. If you could provide a little bit of commentary that explains what you changed to make this work (and possibly switch back to books for consistency instead of posts) this would probably be a better answer.

You are just making your life more complicated.
The general advice is to avoid use of url-rewrites for specifying paths. Instead you should just have something like:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L,QSA]

And use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] on the PHP side to then route the incoming call.
